# Selection of files in Windows 10 File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer

I used to use one of the older versions of Windows 10. I recently upgraded to 1909. While selecting files (or folders) in file explorer (when in List view), I notice that in the older version I had to get very close to the file (or folder) and then click to select. But in the new version, the item gets selected when clicked at a distance.

Same is the case with selecting multiple files. For instance in the older version a drawing a rectangle with the mouse as shown in the 3rd attached picture will select only the Kenny Rogers folder. But in the new one, it selects other folders too.
Is there a way to switch back?

1. Older Versions

   > [image: (1) Older Versions]
2. Newer Windows 10, 1909

   > [image: (2) Newer Windows 10, 1909]
3. Newer Windows 10, 1909

   > [image: (3) Newer Windows 10, 1909]

Comment: What version was the “older version”? File Explorer beyond the view options that exist isn’t really all that customizable.

Comment: Windows 10 is not changing much any more (near end of life). File / Folder spacing is customizable (to some extent) in Windows 11 but not Windows 10. Try using Small Icons in the Windows 10 File Explorer Options.  I am using the most up to date Windows 10

Comment: The older version was 1606 I think (or something with 16 in it). If I remember right the selection was like that since Win 98.

Comment: Small Icons gives the same result as 1909.

Comment: Checked in an XP VM (nothing else on hand) and indeed the behavior was different in the past, though not the selection behavior. You should just accept this change. You'll get used to it. // (Windows 10 1909 is three years out of support.)

Comment: Small Icons gives the same result as 1909   ..............   So there is not much you can do with Windows 10 at this point.

Comment: :) Will try to accept it. As you may have noticed, I am too slow to change. Just went from 1606 to 1909 last week.
Sill miss Windows XP Service Pack 3!!

Comment: Probably time now to rethink. Windows 10 is nearing end of life. Windows 11 is mainstream,and Windows 12 is on the horizon.

Comment: @John: Weren't we told at one point that it was going to be Windows 10 forever (slowly morphing thru updates) ? Or am I imagining that?

Comment: Nope.  Windows 10 will be dead in mid 2025. I know we were told that but Microsoft changed.  So soon Windows 12.  I will install a Pre Release in a VM as soon as I can.

Comment: Also note that some PC's cannot run Windows 11, or not run it well. See if your PC can run Windows 11 before Windows 10 updates stop, or consider getting a new PC, or consider installing Linux, which you can try from USB.